# shell script works but drop error "line[8] expected argument ["

Tags: shell, sh

I have shell script that works (does what i want to do,finds if listed user is online), but each time drop error "line[8] expected argument [". I've tried using == but same thing. There's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
truth=0;
until [ $truth -eq 1 ]
do

    for i; do
    isthere=$(who is here | awk '{print $1}' | grep $i)
    if [ $isthere = $i ] #(8 line is here)
        then
        echo "found user: "$isthere". program now will close.";
        exit 0;
    fi
    done
echo "user not found, retrying after 3sec...";
sleep 3;
done
```

Thank you for you help and time.

Comment: this use "in" all arguments writen bellow script. Example

local@host$ script.sh user1 user2 user3

now for will work like "for i in $user1 $user2 $user3 do"

Comment: @karakfa Iterate over positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, ... `$$#`

Comment: @karafka Yes, the default list is the positional parameters: `set 1 2 3; for i; do echo $i; done` echoes 1 2  3.

Comment: The original question aside, are you sure this does exactly what you expect?  Running `who is there` (or any two arguments) should only return the user on the current tty, so unless you have a `su - otheruser` sessions going, this will either terminate with `found user: $USER. program will now close.` or keep on repeating `"user not found, retrying after 3sec..."`

Comment: it does everything I want. who is there return all online people following info:
[username] [ping] [date] [ip]. I get username with awk and then grep it. If any of positional parameters match with username $isthere and $i will match, if none of parameters match with username $isthere will be null. thats where error accured.

Comment: Which OS/distro?  I would just use plain `who` with no arguments

Comment: I use SunOS 5.11 but its modified by University staff.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld only `who` does actually same thing. Nicely noticed

Comment: `who is there` has no special meaning in any unix/linux version I know. Some version just count the number of arguments, and behave the same as the documented `who am I`.  SunOS 5.x (a bsd+sysv hybrid) dropped or never used that trick.

Comment: this is not bash.  On Solaris, /bin/sh is bourne.

Comment: @SaintHax you are right.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Yes, on my system it just get `who` and then you can write anything you want it will drop same info. `who sgsekgse sgsege` for example also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$isthere` or `$i` is empty. You should quote them: `if [ "$isthere" = "$i" ]`

In other news: most semicolons are useless; a semicolon it is not a statement *terminator*, but a statement *separator*, along with newline.

Comment: Its usually recommended to quote all variables: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Thanks it worked, "isthere" was empty when grep didint found right person. Also if i write `if [ $isthere ]` code also works without erros. can you explain why? or it is just a coinsidence?

Comment: @andlrc when you stuck on that kind of mistake for several hours and end up in forums i totally agree that quoting is recommended and I recommend it myself now also :D

Comment: @PauliusMickus Not only that. But also to prevent unwanted word splitting and globbing.

Comment: @PauliusMickus This is because the `[` command behaves differently depending on the number of arguments. With only one argument it tests if the string is empty. With two, as in `[ = foo ]` it errors, because `foo` is not an operator. The definitive answer is in the POSIX spec for `test`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: With ksh93 (and bash), `[[` ... `]]` can be used instead of the single brackets to automatically quote all parameters.